# Max Pooling in VGG16 Before Global Average Pooling (GAP)?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, vgg-net, torchvision

I am currently using VGG16 with Global Average Pooling (GAP) before final classification layer. The VGG16 model used is the one provided by torchvision.

However, I noticed that before the GAP layer, there is a Max Pooling layer. Is this okay or should the Max Pooling layer be removed before the GAP layer? The network architecture can be seen below.

```
VGG(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (16): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (17): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (18): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (19): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (23): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
    (24): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (25): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (26): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (27): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (28): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (29): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (30): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)   #GAP Layer
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=7, bias=True)
  )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to train the classifier, it should be okay. Nonetheless, I wouldn't remove it either way.

It is worth mentioning that the max-pooling is part of the original architecture, as can be seen in Table 1 of the original paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf.

Comment: Ah okay then. I saw that the max-pooling is indeed part of the original architecture, hence my confusion as to how it should be treated in my modification. Thanks for the answer @Berriel